# Fluctuation in jquery image marquee plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have using jquery crawler plugin for my slider. while sliding there is a Fluctuation in that slider. How can i remove that???

here my code

```
<div id="mycrawler2" class="scroll"> 
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/560x373q90/11/lm0a.jpg" border="0" width="610" height="446" />
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/249x373q90/819/3xi4.jpg" border="0" width="674" height="446" />
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/560x373q90/811/c34l.jpg" border="0" width="726" height="446" />
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/300x400q50/832/oih7.jpg" border="0" width="728" height="446" />
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/373x373q90/844/ybfp.jpg" border="0" width="833" height="446" />
        <img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/273x373q90/689/nkgc.png" border="0" width="834" height="446" />
    </div>
```

here my js

```
marqueeInit({
    uniqueid: 'mycrawler2',
    style: {
        'padding': '0px',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '446px'
    },
    inc: 20, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
    mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
    moveatleast: 3,
    neutral: 150,
    savedirection: true,
    random: true
});
```

here my external js

[Jquery min](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js)

[Crawler](http://bellamalaysia.com/site/js/crawler.js)

Comment: my js fiddle demo
http://jsfiddle.net/dhanil/tQcnE/

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "there is a fluctuation in the slider"?

Comment: your jsfiddle example seems to work well for me. what exactly are you seeing as the bug?

Comment: there is a image delay a small jumping while sliding